# PyQt layouts center element to left in full screen

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm building a simple app with PyQt to be run on an RPi display. I'm also new to PyQt. So, the dimesnsions of the screen aren't gonna change. Hence, I'm comfortable with using a Box Layout or not using a layout at all in this case. But, I want to get the proper result. This app doesn't need to be *responsive* or adaptive or anything.

Here is what I have did so far:

```
class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1920, 1000)

        # layout for date & time display
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        # to prevent unnecessary spacing in full screen
        layout.addStretch()

        self.time = QLabel("Loading", self)
        self.date = QLabel("Loading", self)
    
        self.time.setFont(QFont('Ubuntu', 180))
        self.date.setFont(QFont('Ubuntu', 50))

        layout.addWidget(self.time)
        layout.addWidget(self.date)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)
        timer.start(1000)

    # method called by timer
    def showTime(self):

        current_time = QDateTime.currentDateTime()

        # formatting date and time to string
        date_time = current_time.toString('dddd, MMMM d, yyyy')
        timer_time = current_time.toString('hh:mm AP')

        # setting date & time to the label
        self.time.setText(timer_time)
        self.date.setText(date_time)


App = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = Window()
window.setStyleSheet("background-color: black; color: white; QLabel { margin-bottom: 500 }")
window.show()

App.exit(App.exec_())
```

I also tried not to use a layout at all. By using `class Window(QMainWindow)` instead of `QWidget`. And then I tried to use `move()` to position the date and time correctly. But that produces a weird looking output where both the date and time are confined to another small box inside the main window and aren't completely displayed.

The ideal output that I want is for the date and time to be on the center left of the screen in 1920X1000 size. How can I achieve this?[image: What I have so far (with the above given code)]

In Tkinter, I could do this with grid() and that would be something like:

```
time_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 200, pady = (200, 0)) 
date_label.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 200)
```

This is what the final thing should look like. The spotify and maps logo are buttons in Tkinter. Any help would be appreciated and upvoted.

[image: Ideal Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've added a `stretch` on top of the layout. A stretch is a layout item that expands itself as much as other widgets on the same layout allow it, and in your case the result is that stretch occupies all the available vertical space, by placing other widgets at the bottom.

If you want to vertically center the widgets, just add another `layout.addStretch()` line after adding the widgets.

Note that, even if you don't think you need a layout manager, there are very few and specific situations for which that approach can be considered, and manually setting widget geometries is usually prone to unexpected behavior (and lots of useless headaches).

On the other side, you also want to add other widgets that are probably going to be placed on the right side. To correctly achieve this, nested layouts are the more simple and straightforward solution:

- A "main" QHBoxLayout
- A QVBoxLayout for the left side (the labels) used as you're currently doing
- Another QVBoxLayout for the right side widgets, with a similar behavior

```
class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        mainLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        leftLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(leftLayout)

        # ...
        leftLayout.addStretch()
        layout.addWidget(self.time, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.date, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addStretch()

        rightLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        # ...
        rightLayout.addStretch()
        rightLayout.addWidget(self.spotifyWidget)
        rightLayout.addStretch()
        rightLayout.addWidget(self.gmapWidget)
        rightLayout.addStretch()

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
```

Note that Qt layouts have a commodity constructor that accepts a QWidget as argument, which automatically sets the layout for that widget: you can create the main layout like this:

```
    mainLayout = QHBoxLayout(self)
```

And then you don't need to use `setLayout()`.